# Unrecognized function or variable 'x'

Tags: matlab

```
clear
z=sin(x)+cos(y)/x;
fsurf(z,[0.1 3 -6 8])
```

I want to depict this surface (z=sin(x)+cos(y)/x), but I can't because of it doesn't know x and y, what should I do?
x ∈ [0.1, 3], y ∈ [−6, 8]

Probably I should give an value to x and y, but I don't know how should I do.

Comment: Indeed, you need to assign a value to x and y. Look up `linspace`. You also want to use `./` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add
x = 0.1:0.1:3.0 and y = -6.0:0.8.0